# Is there a PHP date() equivalent in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm attempting to calculate the day of the year (either with today or another date).

In PHP I can use the date() function and do whatever I want...

Is there something similar in JS/jQuery?

Comment: Have a look at [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Surprised nobody posted about moment.js, it's very similar to date.js, but lighter (5.5k minified)

http://momentjs.com/

Just did a benchmark and found it parses much faster than date.js, but formatting and manipulating is slower. For one-liners it'd execute faster than date.js due to the faster parsing.

http://jsperf.com/underscore-date-vs-datejs/7

Some usage examples:

```
// Simulates ajax response
var data = { someDate: "2023-08-23 11:52:39" }

// .unix() converts to Unix timestamp: 1692816759
moment(data.someDate).unix();

// Displaying it in a readable format
// Aug 23, 11:52 AM
moment("2023-08-23 11:52:39").format('MMM D, hh:mm A');

// Now
moment();

// Support for manipulation and chaining
moment().add('days', 7).subtract('months', 1).hours(15).minutes(0).seconds(0);
```

Comment: We've actually started to use this quite a bit. It's great :).

Answer (score 5):

I use **[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)**.

Comment: Wow! that is Awesome! I had never heard of it... excellent find.

Comment: Although this is a really old answer, consider that the OP asked for a similar equivalent to PHP's `date` function in JS. Since there is none built-in, a link to a library is logical. Granted, the answer could have been improved with a code sample, but the "essential part" actually is the link in this case.

Answer (score 3):

According to the authors, [phpjs date()](http://phpjs.org/functions/date/)  is "a JavaScript equivalent of PHP’s date". So if that's what you're looking for, give it a try.

**Edit**

In case the remote site goes down, here's the code (retrieved 2016-02-03):

```
function date(format, timestamp) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/date/
  // original by: Carlos R. L. Rodrigues (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
  // original by: gettimeofday
  //    parts by: Peter-Paul Koch (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/beat.html)
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: MeEtc (http://yass.meetcweb.com)
  // improved by: Brad Touesnard
  // improved by: Tim Wiel
  // improved by: Bryan Elliott
  // improved by: David Randall
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Thomas Beaucourt (http://www.webapp.fr)
  // improved by: JT
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl)
  // improved by: Theriault
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //    input by: majak
  //    input by: Alex
  //    input by: Martin
  //    input by: Alex Wilson
  //    input by: Haravikk
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: majak
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: omid (http://phpjs.org/functions/380:380#comment_137122)
  // bugfixed by: Chris (http://www.devotis.nl/)
  //        note: Uses global: php_js to store the default timezone
  //        note: Although the function potentially allows timezone info (see notes), it currently does not set
  //        note: per a timezone specified by date_default_timezone_set(). Implementers might use
  //        note: this.php_js.currentTimezoneOffset and this.php_js.currentTimezoneDST set by that function
  //        note: in order to adjust the dates in this function (or our other date functions!) accordingly
  //   example 1: date('H:m:s \\m \\i\\s \\m\\o\\n\\t\\h', 1062402400);
  //   returns 1: '09:09:40 m is month'
  //   example 2: date('F j, Y, g:i a', 1062462400);
  //   returns 2: 'September 2, 2003, 2:26 am'
  //   example 3: date('Y W o', 1062462400);
  //   returns 3: '2003 36 2003'
  //   example 4: x = date('Y m d', (new Date()).getTime()/1000);
  //   example 4: (x+'').length == 10 // 2009 01 09
  //   returns 4: true
  //   example 5: date('W', 1104534000);
  //   returns 5: '53'
  //   example 6: date('B t', 1104534000);
  //   returns 6: '999 31'
  //   example 7: date('W U', 1293750000.82); // 2010-12-31
  //   returns 7: '52 1293750000'
  //   example 8: date('W', 1293836400); // 2011-01-01
  //   returns 8: '52'
  //   example 9: date('W Y-m-d', 1293974054); // 2011-01-02
  //   returns 9: '52 2011-01-02'

  var that = this;
  var jsdate, f;
  // Keep this here (works, but for code commented-out below for file size reasons)
  // var tal= [];
  var txt_words = [
    'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wednes', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Satur',
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
  ];
  // trailing backslash -> (dropped)
  // a backslash followed by any character (including backslash) -> the character
  // empty string -> empty string
  var formatChr = /\\?(.?)/gi;
  var formatChrCb = function(t, s) {
    return f[t] ? f[t]() : s;
  };
  var _pad = function(n, c) {
    n = String(n);
    while (n.length < c) {
      n = '0' + n;
    }
    return n;
  };
  f = {
    // Day
    d: function() { // Day of month w/leading 0; 01..31
      return _pad(f.j(), 2);
    },
    D: function() { // Shorthand day name; Mon...Sun
      return f.l()
        .slice(0, 3);
    },
    j: function() { // Day of month; 1..31
      return jsdate.getDate();
    },
    l: function() { // Full day name; Monday...Sunday
      return txt_words[f.w()] + 'day';
    },
    N: function() { // ISO-8601 day of week; 1[Mon]..7[Sun]
      return f.w() || 7;
    },
    S: function() { // Ordinal suffix for day of month; st, nd, rd, th
      var j = f.j();
      var i = j % 10;
      if (i <= 3 && parseInt((j % 100) / 10, 10) == 1) {
        i = 0;
      }
      return ['st', 'nd', 'rd'][i - 1] || 'th';
    },
    w: function() { // Day of week; 0[Sun]..6[Sat]
      return jsdate.getDay();
    },
    z: function() { // Day of year; 0..365
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), f.n() - 1, f.j());
      var b = new Date(f.Y(), 0, 1);
      return Math.round((a - b) / 864e5);
    },

    // Week
    W: function() { // ISO-8601 week number
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), f.n() - 1, f.j() - f.N() + 3);
      var b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
      return _pad(1 + Math.round((a - b) / 864e5 / 7), 2);
    },

    // Month
    F: function() { // Full month name; January...December
      return txt_words[6 + f.n()];
    },
    m: function() { // Month w/leading 0; 01...12
      return _pad(f.n(), 2);
    },
    M: function() { // Shorthand month name; Jan...Dec
      return f.F()
        .slice(0, 3);
    },
    n: function() { // Month; 1...12
      return jsdate.getMonth() + 1;
    },
    t: function() { // Days in month; 28...31
      return (new Date(f.Y(), f.n(), 0))
        .getDate();
    },

    // Year
    L: function() { // Is leap year?; 0 or 1
      var j = f.Y();
      return j % 4 === 0 & j % 100 !== 0 | j % 400 === 0;
    },
    o: function() { // ISO-8601 year
      var n = f.n();
      var W = f.W();
      var Y = f.Y();
      return Y + (n === 12 && W < 9 ? 1 : n === 1 && W > 9 ? -1 : 0);
    },
    Y: function() { // Full year; e.g. 1980...2010
      return jsdate.getFullYear();
    },
    y: function() { // Last two digits of year; 00...99
      return f.Y()
        .toString()
        .slice(-2);
    },

    // Time
    a: function() { // am or pm
      return jsdate.getHours() > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    },
    A: function() { // AM or PM
      return f.a()
        .toUpperCase();
    },
    B: function() { // Swatch Internet time; 000..999
      var H = jsdate.getUTCHours() * 36e2;
      // Hours
      var i = jsdate.getUTCMinutes() * 60;
      // Minutes
      var s = jsdate.getUTCSeconds(); // Seconds
      return _pad(Math.floor((H + i + s + 36e2) / 86.4) % 1e3, 3);
    },
    g: function() { // 12-Hours; 1..12
      return f.G() % 12 || 12;
    },
    G: function() { // 24-Hours; 0..23
      return jsdate.getHours();
    },
    h: function() { // 12-Hours w/leading 0; 01..12
      return _pad(f.g(), 2);
    },
    H: function() { // 24-Hours w/leading 0; 00..23
      return _pad(f.G(), 2);
    },
    i: function() { // Minutes w/leading 0; 00..59
      return _pad(jsdate.getMinutes(), 2);
    },
    s: function() { // Seconds w/leading 0; 00..59
      return _pad(jsdate.getSeconds(), 2);
    },
    u: function() { // Microseconds; 000000-999000
      return _pad(jsdate.getMilliseconds() * 1000, 6);
    },

    // Timezone
    e: function() { // Timezone identifier; e.g. Atlantic/Azores, ...
      // The following works, but requires inclusion of the very large
      // timezone_abbreviations_list() function.
      /*              return that.date_default_timezone_get();
       */
      throw 'Not supported (see source code of date() for timezone on how to add support)';
    },
    I: function() { // DST observed?; 0 or 1
      // Compares Jan 1 minus Jan 1 UTC to Jul 1 minus Jul 1 UTC.
      // If they are not equal, then DST is observed.
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), 0);
      // Jan 1
      var c = Date.UTC(f.Y(), 0);
      // Jan 1 UTC
      var b = new Date(f.Y(), 6);
      // Jul 1
      var d = Date.UTC(f.Y(), 6); // Jul 1 UTC
      return ((a - c) !== (b - d)) ? 1 : 0;
    },
    O: function() { // Difference to GMT in hour format; e.g. +0200
      var tzo = jsdate.getTimezoneOffset();
      var a = Math.abs(tzo);
      return (tzo > 0 ? '-' : '+') + _pad(Math.floor(a / 60) * 100 + a % 60, 4);
    },
    P: function() { // Difference to GMT w/colon; e.g. +02:00
      var O = f.O();
      return (O.substr(0, 3) + ':' + O.substr(3, 2));
    },
    T: function() { // Timezone abbreviation; e.g. EST, MDT, ...
      // The following works, but requires inclusion of the very
      // large timezone_abbreviations_list() function.
      /*              var abbr, i, os, _default;
      if (!tal.length) {
        tal = that.timezone_abbreviations_list();
      }
      if (that.php_js && that.php_js.default_timezone) {
        _default = that.php_js.default_timezone;
        for (abbr in tal) {
          for (i = 0; i < tal[abbr].length; i++) {
            if (tal[abbr][i].timezone_id === _default) {
              return abbr.toUpperCase();
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (abbr in tal) {
        for (i = 0; i < tal[abbr].length; i++) {
          os = -jsdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
          if (tal[abbr][i].offset === os) {
            return abbr.toUpperCase();
          }
        }
      }
      */
      return 'UTC';
    },
    Z: function() { // Timezone offset in seconds (-43200...50400)
      return -jsdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
    },

    // Full Date/Time
    c: function() { // ISO-8601 date.
      return 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
    },
    r: function() { // RFC 2822
      return 'D, d M Y H:i:s O'.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
    },
    U: function() { // Seconds since UNIX epoch
      return jsdate / 1000 | 0;
    }
  };
  this.date = function(format, timestamp) {
    that = this;
    jsdate = (timestamp === undefined ? new Date() : // Not provided
      (timestamp instanceof Date) ? new Date(timestamp) : // JS Date()
      new Date(timestamp * 1000) // UNIX timestamp (auto-convert to int)
    );
    return format.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
  };
  return this.date(format, timestamp);
}
```

Note: Php.js is licensed under MIT license. See http://phpjs.org/about/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you're coming from PHP, you might enjoy this port of strftime to JS.

https://hacks.bluesmoon.info/strftime/demo.html

```
var dateObj = new Date('2011/11/11');
var dayOfYear = dateObj.strftime("%j");
```

I've used it a bunch and it's great. I believe it's significantly lighter weight than Datejs.

Answer (score 2):

I use the **[date_to_string() function](https://github.com/andrewgjohnson/date_to_string)**

```
/*
 * date_to_string v1.0.0
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Andrew G. Johnson <andrew@andrewgjohnson.com>
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * @author Andrew G. Johnson <andrew@andrewgjohnson.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2013 Andrew G. Johnson <andrew@andrewgjohnson.com>
 * @link http://github.com/andrewgjohnson/date_to_string
 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @package date_to_string
 *
 */

if (typeof date_to_string == "undefined")
{
    var date_to_string = function(format,date) {
        format = String(format);
        date = typeof date != "undefined" && date instanceof Date ? date : new Date();

        var formats = {
            a:function(date) {
                return date.getHours() < 12 ? "am" : "pm";
            },
            A:function(date) {
                return date.getHours() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
            },
            B:function(date) {
                return ("000" + Math.floor((date.getHours() * 60 * 60 + (date.getMinutes() + 60 + date.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 + date.getSeconds()) / 86.4) % 1000).slice(-3);
            },
            c:function(date) {
                return date_to_string("Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",date);
            },
            d:function(date) {
                return (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getDate();
            },
            D:function(date) {
                switch (date.getDay())
                {
                    case 0:
                        return "Sun";

                    case 1:
                        return "Mon";

                    case 2:
                        return "Tue";

                    case 3:
                        return "Wed";

                    case 4:
                        return "Thu";

                    case 5:
                        return "Fri";

                    case 6:
                        return "Sat";
                }
            },
            e:function(date) {
                var
                    first = parseInt(Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60),10),
                    second = Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() % 60);
                return (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? "+" : "-") + (first < 10 ? "0" : "") + first + (second < 10 ? "0" : "") + second;
            },
            F:function(date) {
                switch (date.getMonth())
                {
                    case 0:
                        return "January";

                    case 1:
                        return "February";

                    case 2:
                        return "March";

                    case 3:
                        return "April";

                    case 4:
                        return "May";

                    case 5:
                        return "June";

                    case 6:
                        return "July";

                    case 7:
                        return "August";

                    case 8:
                        return "September";

                    case 9:
                        return "October";

                    case 10:
                        return "November";

                    case 11:
                        return "December";
                }
            },
            g:function(date) {
                return date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
            },
            G:function(date) {
                return date.getHours();
            },
            h:function(date) {
                var hour = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
                return (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
            },
            H:function(date) {
                return (date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getHours();
            },
            i:function(date) {
                return (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getMinutes();
            },
            I:function(date) {
                return date.getTimezoneOffset() < Math.max(new Date(date.getFullYear(),0,1).getTimezoneOffset(),new Date(date.getFullYear(),6,1).getTimezoneOffset()) ? 1 : 0;
            },
            j:function(date) {
                return date.getDate();
            },
            l:function(date) {
                switch (date.getDay())
                {
                    case 0:
                        return "Sunday";

                    case 1:
                        return "Monday";

                    case 2:
                        return "Tuesday";

                    case 3:
                        return "Wednesday";

                    case 4:
                        return "Thursday";

                    case 5:
                        return "Friday";

                    case 6:
                        return "Saturday";
                }
            },
            L:function(date) {
                return new Date(date.getFullYear(),1,29).getMonth() == 1 ? 1 : 0;
            },
            m:function(date) {
                return (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? "0" : "") + (date.getMonth() + 1);
            },
            M:function(date) {
                switch (date.getMonth())
                {
                    case 0:
                        return "Jan";

                    case 1:
                        return "Feb";

                    case 2:
                        return "Mar";

                    case 3:
                        return "Apr";

                    case 4:
                        return "May";

                    case 5:
                        return "Jun";

                    case 6:
                        return "Jul";

                    case 7:
                        return "Aug";

                    case 8:
                        return "Sep";

                    case 9:
                        return "Oct";

                    case 10:
                        return "Nov";

                    case 11:
                        return "Dec";
                }
            },
            n:function(date) {
                return date.getMonth() + 1;
            },
            N:function(date) {
                return date.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : date.getDay();
            },
            o:function(date) {
                return date.getWeekYear();
            },
            O:function(date) {
                var
                    first = parseInt(Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60),10),
                    second = Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() % 60);
                return (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? "+" : "-") + (first < 10 ? "0" : "") + first + (second < 10 ? "0" : "") + second;
            },
            P:function(date) {
                var
                    first = parseInt(Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60),10),
                    second = Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() % 60);
                return (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? "+" : "-") + (first < 10 ? "0" : "") + first + ":" + (second < 10 ? "0" : "") + second;
            },
            r:function(date) {
                return date_to_string("D, d M Y H:i:s O",date);
            },
            s:function(date) {
                return (date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" : "") + date.getSeconds();
            },
            S:function(date) {
                switch (date.getDate())
                {
                    case 1:
                    case 21:
                    case 31:
                        return "st";

                    case 2:
                    case 22:
                        return "nd";

                    case 3:
                    case 23:
                        return "rd";

                    default:
                        return "th";
                }
            },
            t:function(date) {
                return new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth() + 1,0).getDate();
            },
            T:function(date) {
                var abbreviation = String(date).match(/\(([^\)]+)\)$/) || String(date).match(/([A-Z]+) [\d]{4}$/);
                if (abbreviation)
                    abbreviation = abbreviation[1].match(/[A-Z]/g).join("");
                return abbreviation;
            },
            u:function(date) {
                return date.getMilliseconds() * 1000;
            },
            U:function(date) {
                return Math.round(date.getTime() / 1000);
            },
            w:function(date) {
                return date.getDay();
            },
            W:function(date) {
                return date.getWeek();
            },
            y:function(date) {
                return String(date.getFullYear()).substring(2,4);
            },
            Y:function(date) {
                return date.getFullYear();
            },
            z:function(date) {
                return Math.floor((date.getTime() - new Date(date.getFullYear(),0,1).getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            },
            Z:function(date) {
                return (date.getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? "+" : "-") + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 24);
            }
        };

        var
            string = "",
            escaped = false;
        for (var position = 0;position < format.length;position++)
        {
            if (!escaped && format.substring(position,position + 1) == "\\")
                escaped = true;
            else if (escaped || typeof formats[format.substring(position,position + 1)] == "undefined")
            {
                string += String(format.substring(position,position + 1));
                escaped = false;
            }
            else
                string += String(formats[format.substring(position,position + 1)](date));
        }
        return string;
    };
}

// http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33796/14863/calculate-iso-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var target = new Date(this.valueOf());
    var dayNr = (this.getDay() + 6) % 7;
    target.setDate(target.getDate() - dayNr + 3);
    var firstThursday = target.valueOf();
    target.setMonth(0,1);
    if (target.getDay() != 4) {
        target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - target.getDay()) + 7) % 7);
    }
    return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - target) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
};
Date.prototype.getWeekYear = function() {
    var target  = new Date(this.valueOf());
    target.setDate(target.getDate() - ((this.getDay() + 6) % 7) + 3);
    return target.getFullYear();
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed: one simple function addition to get the job done. Thanks!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11105721)

Comment: @AndrewBrooke This is an attempt to answer the question even if the link markup is removed. This answer should not have been flagged, and therefore should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4639281) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/288751)

Comment: @TinyGiant upon another look, I think you're right. Would it be better however for the answer to provide at least an example of the use of this function?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Sure it would be better. It would be great if the author could include a detailed explanation as well, but as it was when you reviewed it, it shouldn't have been recommended for deletion because it should never have been flagged in the first place. Remember that in the LQPRQ you are voting on whether or not the answer should have been flagged, not whether you think it should be deleted. The flagging system and LQPRQ are not substitutes for delete votes. There is a reason that you have to wait until you have 20k to vote to delete answers.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need full timezone support (North American timezones only),
I wrote a very fast, fully compatible [`phpdate()`](https://npmjs.org/package/phpdate-js)
and matching `gmdate()`
that exactly emulate the php `date` and `gmdate` functions.  (The unit tests
have a fuzz test that format random timestamps and compare against php;
I've run several hundred thousand timestamps while testing.)
I wrote it for nodejs, but if someone helps, I'd be willing to port
it to pure js.

All the conversion specifiers are supported; no external dependencies.

ISO week and year numbering, day-of-week and leap-year info is extracted
from Date().  Timezone information is reverse engineered from the UTC offset
made available by Date().