# jQuery: pass string variable to date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, date-arithmetic

I have a page with a number of variables that contain a **date in string format (yyyy-mm-dd)** which originates from using moment.js.

Is there a way I can pass such a variable to a Javascript date object resp. to convert it to a Javascript date object ?
I am not interested in the time so as long as I can get the date converted to a date object that would be great.

I tried the following but this doesn't work and I couldn't find a way using moment.js:

```
var newVar = new Date(dateVar);
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: you can call to toDate() method of momentjs instead of getting it as a string...

Comment: Refer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099681/is-there-a-php-date-equivalent-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: `var newVar = new Date(dateVar);` seems to be working for me. Try `new Date("2014-03-05")` in the console

Answer (score 28, accepted):

first of all i will say following should work for you..

```
var dateVar = "2010-10-30";
var d=new Date(dateVar);
```

if you say above not working check the below one -

```
var dateVar = "2010-10-30";
var dsplit = dateVar.split("-");
var d=new Date(dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1,dsplit[2]);
```

for the proof check the jsfiddle.. both is working fine.. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NRz97/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second one works fine for me. Would that be faster than using Regex in such a case ?

Comment: Regex for what?? to split the date string?? i will suggest you to use the same code.. as we just need to split the string with **Hyphen (-)** which is a simple task. so i will not suggest you to create one more object just to split ..

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the explanation, this works great - just wanted to check. Thanks again !

Answer (score 5):

`console.log()` has been use to show the output , run this and you will understand the code

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var StringDate = "2013-4-13"
    var date = StringDate.split("-"); 
    console.log(date[0]);
    console.log(date[1]);
    console.log(date[2]);

    NewDate = new Date(date[0],date[1]-1,date[2]);//Date object
    console.log(NewDate);
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks good ! As I have to do this with several strings in a row I would like to have less code for each of them. Is there a way to achieve the same with Regex as well ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I a made function who manage the change from text to date:

My examples works with date as this: Jun/1/2016 to 2016-06-01 you can rebuild the function to make your format works...

The cero's at the left of the numbers are added to match the date type format.

```
function textoafecha(texto)
        {

            hasNumber = /\d/;

            // Contiene el pedazo del texto que contiene el mes
            mestexto = texto.substr(0,3);
            // Contiene el pedazo de texto que contiene el primer numero del dia
            diatextonumero1 = texto.substr(4,1);
            diatextonumero2 = texto.substr(5,1);

            // Si el texo contiene un numero...
            if (hasNumber.test(diatextonumero2))
               {
                 dia = texto.substr(4,2);
                 anotexto = texto.substr(7,4);
               }
            else
               {
                 dia = texto.substr(4,1);
                 dia = "0"+ dia;
                 anotexto = texto.substr(6,4); 
               }


            switch (mestexto) 
            {
              case "Jan" : mesnumero = "01";
                           break;   

              case "Feb" : mesnumero = "02";
                           break;   

              case "Mar" : mesnumero = "03";
                           break;   

              case "Apr" : mesnumero = "04";
                           break;   

              case "May" : mesnumero = "05";
                           break;   

              case "Jun" : mesnumero = "06";
                           break;   

              case "Jul" : mesnumero = "07";
                           break;   

              case "Aug" : mesnumero = "08";
                           break;   

              case "Sep" : mesnumero = "09";
                           break;   

              case "Oct" : mesnumero = "10";
                           break;   

              case "Nov" : mesnumero = "11";
                           break;   

              case "Dec" : mesnumero = "12";
                           break;   

              default : break;

            }

            fechaformateada = anotexto + "-" + mesnumero + "-" + dia;           
            return fechaformateada;

        }
```

Comment: your last case should be `Dec` not `Dic` :P

Comment: Sorry that my first language -> Spanish uses "i" instead of "e" on December, Diciembre