# how can I create a new Date object in jquery based on the date object returned from php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datetime

I have a php script that returns date in tokyo in a following format:

```
Thu, 01 Oct 2015 06:10:09 +0900
```

I already passed it to my jquery script with ajax and now store it in local variable

```
var myTime = 'Thu, 01 Oct 2015 06:10:09 +0900
```

Now I want to create a new `Date()` object with that data, so then I can have an actual date from tokyo on my webpage without using local client's timezone. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188215/jquery-pass-string-variable-to-date-object/ You also may want to reference the following: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP code returns just that string:

```
<?PHP echo "Thu, 01 Oct 2015 06:10:09 +0900"; ?>
```

Then in your jQuery ajax return:

```
function(data) 
{
    var myDate = new Date(data.trim());
    //...
}//..
```

Example: of the raw string in jsfiddle
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gac2rhyg/1/)